EEPROM wear leveling between power cycles
I have an EEPROM with 2kb memory available to store some data - 8 bytes per write.
I need to write this data every second, and currently I don't have the ability to change the EEPROM to FRAM or a better EEPROM so I have to use what I have(AT24C32, 2kb of which are free for this purpose).
Writing to this EEPROM every second will likely kill it rather quickly, as it doesn't have that many write cycles for that(it's a device that will run at least 12 hours a day).
I tried to look into wear leveling algorithms as that should spread the wear across the 2kb evenly and should increase the longevity of the EEPROM.
The main issue I encountered is that I need the data to be saved between power cycles.
Let's assume that this device keeps the time in 8 bytes format, I've seen some examples of wear leveling algorithms, but ones that work between power cycles usually keep the current memory index in a static location, that means that while the wear will spread across most of the 2kb, 1 byte for the index will still be written to, and if we write every second to that static memory, assuming 12 hours per day, it should die within a month or so.
Is there a wear leveling algorithm that could have a dynamic memory for the position so the whole 2kb will wear evenly without encountering this possible issue?

I'd guess that a 2 byte counter appended to each record would do the job? Shouldn't be too hard to detect the latest write on startup

Algorithms are language agnostic.  You can remove the C and C++ language tags.  Providing code is off-topic for StackOverflow.

@AlanBirtles I basically want the minimum amount of writes per cycle. Jerry's solution seems to reset and write each byte, so for 8 bytes and 2kb it would write 512 times per cycle.
With the counter approach I think I still need to write and reset, so I'm not sure if it reduces the writing time per cycle, though not entirely sure.

No need to reset, if you use a 2 byte counter you'd end up with 204 records, it should then be fairly easy to work out which is the most recently written record, you could even get away with a single byte counter but it might be a little harder to work out which is the most recent record

@AlanBirtles Would you mind elaborating on how the counter works with either 1 or 2 bytes? Not really sure I understood how you would know the position after a full cycle.
Thanks.

Wherever the last record was written there'll be a discontinuity in the sequence of the counters

@AlanBirtles Sorry, still not sure I fully understood how you meant to use the counter. If you'd like to write some explanation that would be nice.

There's a pretty easy way to do this, as long as there's at least one bit pattern in the 8-byte record that wouldn't be a legitimate value. If they are time-stamps, it's probably pretty easy to do this (and probably pretty easy to store a lot more timestamps in your 2kb than just storing 8 bytes per timestamp).
For the moment, let's assume legitimate records all contain at least one non-zero byte.
In this case, we start by initializing the memory to 0's, indicating that it's empty. Then we write non-zero values to successive locations, and (probably) use a location in RAM to indicate where the next write will go.
When the system is powered on, we find the border between zero and non-zero locations, initialize our counter, and off we go.
It looks like your EEPROM is composed of pages of 32 bytes apiece. So, you can probably erase a page, then fill that page with data. Just before you write the last 8-byte chunk of that page, you erase the next page, so at any given time you have at least one 8-byte chunk that's been erased, so if you lose power you'll be able to find the location of the last record that was written.
If it is timestamps, you can break each timestamp into two pieces. The high bits will/would change only when the lower bits roll over to 0. So you'd probably want to do something like 6 upper bytes and 2 lower bytes. This way, the upper bytes are written only once very ~65535 writes to the lower bytes. You can store (almost) 4 times as many timestamps in the same memory--which should roughly quadruple your device life as well.

Just adding some additional info. The AT24C32 has 1 million write cycles, given 2kb and a 8 byte write every second spread over that 2kb will result in a lifetime of around 8 years. But it will probably be longer, 1M is just the specified write cycles in the datasheet, it will probably be able to handle more.

Thanks a lot for the reply!
I wrote a simple code example(pseudo mostly, didn't test it):
https://pastebin.com/C7zwAaR0
I think this is what you meant? That basically means that for each byte I need to write twice, once to pre-reset the following page before reaching it, and 1 time to write the data.
So writing 8 bytes to 2kb will be 256 chunks x 2 = 512 writes per cycle? aka every 256 seconds.
@Fredrik Since each memory needs 1 action to write and 1 action to clear, I think that results in 4 years? Not sure if I'm off, it's a bit late here and I'm tired :)

@msacco: Quite a few EEPROMs/FLASH ROMs support a page erase that doesn't count as a write, but looking at the data sheet, that doesn't seem to be the case here, so yeah, this would roughly halve the endurance.

@msacco why does the write need to happen every second?

@msacco also in your example code, do the lookup for the start address once during startup and keep it in a RAM variable.

"initializing the memory to 0's, indicating that it's empty" That's very strange. Normally, "all ones" is the empty state for every flash memory I've ever worked with. And writing a zero to a cell with value 1 is what causes wear. Also, zero is a very likely value for a data cell to hold.

@Lundin: I'ts purely an arbitrary choice, which I thought was pretty clear from: "For the moment, let's assume legitimate records all contain at least one non-zero byte.". As far as zero vs one to erase: that's almost entirely a question of how often the signal happens to be inverted between the pin and the cell, and varies between one memory chip and the next.
